# Selecting an IEnumerable<Class> into a new IEnumerable<Class2>

Tags: c#, linq, ienumerable

I have a class such as this:

```
public class MyClass
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

And I have a second class:

```
public class SelectableItem
{
    public MyClass Item { get; set; }
    public bool Selected { get; set; }
}
```

I have an `IEnumerable` list of `MyClass`, and I want to read that list into `SelectableItem`; something like this:

```
IEnumerable<MyClass> class1List = FillListWithStuff();
IEnumerable<SelectableItem> newList = { class1List.Where(p => p.Name == "test"), false};
```

So that `newList` contains all the elements of `class1List`, and they are marked as `Selected = false`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need a `Select` since you are not performing any filtering:

```
class1List.Select(x => new SelectableItem { Item = x, Selected = false });
```

Comment: I was just writing this ))

Comment: You don't even need to explicitly assign `Selected` to `false`.

Comment: Thanks - couldn't remember the exact syntax

Answer (score 1):

For those who prefer query syntax:

```
var newList = from class1 in class1List
              select new SelectableItem { Item = class1 };
```

This will of course be transformed before compilation to

```
var newList = class1List.Select(class1 => new SelectableItem { Item = class1 });
```

as per Selman22's answer.

Answer (score 0):

Use a Select and copy the Item value from the value in your first list and set the Selected to false.

```
IEnumerable<SelectableItem> newList = class1List.Select(x => new SelectableItem { Item = x.Item, Selected = false});
```